# Command-line flags in quines

Tags: discussion

For languages that use command-line flags to modify their behavior, these flags are generally added to the byte count. But I don't see a ruling on what to do with command-line flags in [quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quine) challenges. I.e. suppose this was a quine: `perl -ne 'quine_program'`. I see a few options:

- **Output the flags.** They are part of the source code: their bytes are counted as such, and the program wouldn't work without them. Con: how to format them? Outputting `nquine_program` would indicate that the code was `nquine_program`, not `quine_program` with the `n` flag. Maybe a newline in between?
- **Don't output the flags.** They are not really part of the source code, as the objection to the above point shows. Con: this opens all the same loopholes that not counting flags in the byte count opens.
- **Flags are banned in quine challenges.** They're too much of a corner case. Do what you need to do in the code itself. Con: flags are really useful and idiomatic (maybe even necessary) for some languages.

What say ye?

Comment: I think saying flags are "useful and idiomatic" is an understatement [some languages](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/69/golf-you-a-quine-for-great-good/95296#95296) cannot print a Quine without some command line flag.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## A quine outputs its source code verbatim

That sounds like stating the obvious, but the answer is right there - nowhere in the definition of a quine is there any reference to command-line arguments. For the purposes of quining, the only output should be the source code. Any non-standard command-line arguments don't matter except for the byte penalty.

So, to use your example, the program `quine_program`, run with `perl -ne 'quine_program'`, should output `quine_program`, and would have a score of 14 bytes (13 for the source code plus 1 for the non-standard command-line flag).

Comment: I like this answer, but how does it apply to the `-D` flag in C? If we allow `-D` under these rules, then I can write a C quine in 28 bytes: code is `A`, compilation option `-D'A=main(){printf("A");}'` Seems like cheating. Do we want to make an exception for `-D`, as the answers [here](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/19/16766) suggest?

Comment: @DLosc That should be added as a standard loophole, if it's not already covered by one already.

Comment: Hm. It *might* fall under [Outsourcing the real answer](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1085/16766); *somewhat* related to [Using the program name to store data](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1072/16766); but no, I don't think it's really covered by the current loopholes, possibly because we already found a way to make the bytes count (well, most of them). I don't have time to type up a loophole answer right now, but if you do I'll upvote it.

Comment: @DLosc Unfortunately, I don't have time right now, either. If nobody's done it by this evening (my time), I'll write one up.

Comment: I'm not sure if a loophole is necessary, as a quine that uses `-D` doesn't work under our current definition of a quine: "It must be possible to identify a section of the program which encodes a different part of the program. ("Different" meaning that the two parts appear in different positions.)"

Comment: @NathanMerrill Good point. What about code `AB`, flags `-D'A=main(){' -D'B=printf("AB");}'`? The B in the code encodes both the A and the B; the A is just needed to make the B part run.

Comment: I'd still argue at that point that the -D option is doing the encoding, not the "B"

Comment: I would say that command line flags are allowed as long as they don't include _logic_ - for example, a flag to print the last evaluated expression is ok, a flag that encodes the program is not allowed. However, it's hard to draw the line.